# How to display points with QT3D?

Tags: qt, qt3d

Qt3D makes it very easy to display some mesh primitives:

```
m_torus = new Qt3DExtras::QTorusMesh();
```

but I would just like to display a collection of points. I haven't seen anything like

```
m_points = new Qt3DExtras::QPoints();
```

Is there a way to do this without writing lower level OpenGL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know if this is what you're looking for but check out `Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer`. I use it in a project to display map lines in a 3D scene.
There is a method to define how the vertex buffer data shall be rendered (where I use `Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::LineStrip` instead of `Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::Points`):

```
Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::Points);
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like what I was looking for. However, I've decided not to use this approach at all because of the insane lack of examples/documentation!

Comment: Thank you for this. This may work in **C++**, however it still does not work in Python with **PySide2** module. This module is still under development and hopefully this will work in a near future.

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, There are no simple primitives like lines or points available in Qt3D 2.0, because there is just no one-size-fits-it-all solution. If you are lucky, someone will step up and add something to extras, else you have to write your solution yourself.

[Qt Interest Mailing List Nov 2016 - Lines in Qt3D](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2016-November/024985.html)

There is however, a `pcl` point cloud renderer project [on github](https://github.com/MASKOR/Qt3DPointcloudRenderer)!